# Snprintf: why not report error when second argument over destination memory

Tags: c++, c, linux, printf

This is my code in CentOS6.6, but I don't know why can run normal .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char str[10]={0};
  snprintf(str,18,"0123456789012345678");
  printf("str=%s\n",str);
   return 0;
 }
```

> $ ./test
>
> str=01234567890123456

Why not report the error when 18 over `sizeof(str)`?

I think it would be Segmentation fault, but nothing is reported. I use CentOS6.6.

Comment: "I think it would be Segmentation fault" --> C does not require code to catch itself when it falls.  Especially when code lies to itself `char str[10];   snprintf(str,18,...`  Welcome to programming [without a net](http://sandiegofreepress.org/2016/04/working-without-a-net/).

Answer (score 1):

Accessing memory beyond the allocated chunk is an Undefined behavior.

Segmentation fault is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you". But the reverse is not true i.e you can not say that you'll get a segmentation fault whenever you access an un-allocated memory.

There are systems out there that operate without memory protection, thus you cannot tell whether a piece of memory actually "belongs to you", and thus don't know whether segmentation fault will occur or not, only undefined behavior is assured.

Answer (score 1):

C natively does not have any boundary checking. Access out of bound memory is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It can cause run-time error (in form of segmentation fault) or simply overwrite some other memory area (corrupting some other variable/memory location) and *run fine*. IT's simply undefined.

That said, the purpose of having (using) `snprintf()` is to supply the length properly to avoid out of bound memory access over `sprintf()`. You should use it in proper way, something like

```
snprintf(str,sizeof(str),"0123456789012345678");
```

because, as mentioned in `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.5

> [...] Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are
>   discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end
>   of the characters actually written into the array. [..]

which makes sense of using `snprintf()` over `sprintf()`.

Comment: I think "C natively does not have any boundary checking." is a good explain to why it don't report error.